# How to manually browse source code when using a symbol server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debug-symbols

I'm using [Proget](http://inedo.com/proget) as my own NuGet server and symbol source server. I pushed some packages with symbols and I can step into them while debugging which is great. My problem is, I cannot figure out how to manually ask Visual Studio to e.g. show me the source code of a class. I can only do that if I do "step into" in debug mode, but I want to be able to manually browse the source while not in debug mode.

Sounds like such a simple thing, but I can't find any way to do it.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @CodyGray Seems like you are, unfortunately, right. I don't understand how they missed such an obvious feature.

Comment: Well, it is not designed as a browser. The point of a symbol server is to allow you to step into library code when you're debugging, and it serves that purpose adequately. You'd have to build a browser and parse the code for display purposes. I don't think it'd be as simple as you make it sound.